# Parsing contents of paragraph elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, regex, nokogiri

I'd like to know the proper way to parse a block of contents with Nokogiri:

I have some documents to parse where they originally contained a format where each main container was a `<p>`. The main pieces of information within each one are divided up, oddly, with `<font>` tags.

Effectively a stock sample of `<p>` contents contains the following and is a typical example (some have a lot more content, some a lot less):

```
<p>
  <font size="5" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#00CCAA" class="">
    <font color="#AAFF33" class="">
      October 10, 1990 - Maybe a Title
    </font>- 
    <font size="4" class="">
      Some long text here.         
      <font color="#66CC00" class="">
        <a href="SourceTitle/date.pdf">[Blah Blah, October 27, 1982 p. 2</a>
        ]
      </font>. 
      More content. 
      <font color="#00FF33" class="">[Another Source, 1971, issue 01/4]
      </font>. 
    </font>
    <font size="5" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#00CCAA" class="">
      <font color="#AAFF33" class=""><font size="4" color="#00CCAA" class="">
        Another fantastic article. 
        <a href="SourceTitle/Date.pdf">[Some Source, October 4, p.6]</a>
      </font>
    </font>
  </font>
</font>
</p>
```

Essentially the "font size" attribute is what sets each component apart in the article.  The main points to extract are the FIRST `<font size ="5"...` (that is the article date and main title, if a title is given) tags, then the actual content.

Presently I have all paragraph chunks coming out with: `doc.xpath('//p').each do |node|`

However I am not sure if I should pass it through Nokogiri again to parse out it's contents or if I should just run it all through a regex.  Was hoping for a small example of doing this "properly" with, I'm assuming, using an embedded xpath discovery within the initial block that pulls the elements out.  I assume that there is a way to pull out the sub components based on the font size demarcation, but I've simply not seen a specific example of this yet.

Comment: Could you give an example of target document that you want to get?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide an actual example of the data as it is private information contained in the content.  I've extracted a couple of "rows" of information for your review in context of the entire body: http://j.mp/qbpJnh

Comment: There is some kind of misunderstanding. I mean example of document that you want to get as result

Comment: Sorry @WarHog the output really wasn't important per se inasmuch as I can simply parse out the chunks.  I can use regex, whatever to yank out strings and such.  I just needed to know about xpathing inside an xpath as it was about 4 am and my brain was too foggy to think anymore... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that help you get started?

```
>> doc.xpath('//p').each do |node|
..     puts node.xpath("font[@size='5']/font").first.content.strip
..   end #=> 0
October 10, 1990 - Maybe a Title
```

Build similar expressions for the other parts you need and you are done :-)

Comment: Okay, real quick, the objects emitted are `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, however I'm getting an undefined method for `content` in this case.  Hmm, not seeing a quick answer yet.

Comment: Sorry, hard to tell from here. Play around IRB, inspect the elements, use other introspection methods (like `instance_methods`) etc. It's probably just a minor thing...

Comment: Right, been playing here.  Turns out there was an unexpected "color" style applied to each font that actually indicates the "title" from the rest.  This is causing it to return some nils.  I'm looking into how to have both the font `size` and `color` now in the match string.  I.e., I'd guess that it would have been something like `"font[@size='5',@color='FFFF33']/font"`, but no dice yet.

Comment: And what the heck, I can no longer grep google with phrases like: `+"@size=" and +"@color=" +nokogiri and xpath`  >:(

Comment: It should be `font[@size='5' and @color='#FFFF33']/font`.